# Swift Combine in a NSManagedObject extension

Tags: swift, core-data, combine

I have a `NSManagedObject` which as a url string field for an image. After creation, or if it is somehow missing, I trigger the download of the image and store it in the attribute `imageData` as data. (The images are small, so no performance issues.) I tried to do this in an extension of the managed object.

But how can I set up a `Combine` publisher when I have no way to store it? Usually, I have some object where I can store a `AnyCancellable` or `Set<AnyCancellable>`.

```
extension Object {
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable  <-- Not possible in an extension

    func downloadImage(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
             .tryMap ... // etc
             .sink(...   // etc
                 imageData = data
                 ...
                     try context.save()
                 ...
              )
    }
}
```

Note: It works by falling back to `URSession.dataTask` which provides a callback, but we need to stick to the `Combine` framework in our project.

Comment: How about just *returning* the `AnyCancellable` and let the caller handle it?

Comment: Hmm, good thinking @Sweeper but the caller is a decoder in another `Combine` pipeline, also pretty transient. Maybe that's the right track though. The functionality would be defined in the extension, which is what is desired.

Comment: Another idea is to return a `AnyPublisher<Void, Error>` and use `handleEvents` instead of `sink`. This way the caller can also know when the download is done, or in your case, perhaps you can put it in a `flatMap`? What does the caller look like exactly?

Comment: How about if you use neither a callback nor Combine, but `async/await`?

Comment: There is nothing bad about `URLSession.shared.dataTask`, so I see no need to go further low-level. I was curious about how to use a Publisher.